# git branch rebase common convention

Tags: git, jira, git-branch, rebase, pull-request

I am working on a project having a master branch with some base code.
Then I **made a branch** **develop1** and committed and push to remote and requested for pull request.

Okay, then I want to do another task but in-fact the pull request is not yet completed, is not yet merged with master.

So in this situation if I **create a branch** **develop2** and **rebase it with develop1** and write some codes and **pushed it to remote** what will happen is everything will be okay with out conflict and **could I request for pull request for** **develop2** is it possible?
Or is this the common convention while working with pull request?

Answer (score 0):

If:

- `develop2` does *not* depend on `develop1`
- must be merged to `master`

You should:

- fetch
- create `develop2` from `origin/master`
- work, push `develop2` and request a separate pull-request

---

If `develop2` depends on `develop1`, create it from `develop1`, and once `develop1` is accepted (merged to `master`):

- fetch
- rebase `develop2` to `master`

  ```
    git rebase --onto origin/master develop1 develop2
  ```

That will rebase all commits done *after* your `develop1` local branch, up to your `develop2` HEAD.

- push develop2, make a pull-request.